# Compiler chooses template specialization when passing default template type argument

Tags: c++

Given the following class template + specialization:

```
template<class T = int>
struct S { static constexpr int value = 1; };

template<>
struct S<> { static constexpr int value = 2; };
```

When instantiating with:

```
S<int>::value
```

the compiler instantiates the specialization with value = 2. My question is, why does the compiler behave that way? Isn't the specialization for the case that I do not provide any type? I think I have problems understanding default template arguments.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The specialization is chosen because it satisfies the instantiation (with `T = int`) and is more specialized than the template.

When declaring the specialization `template<> struct S<>`, `T` is implicitly set to `int` because it's the default value (or rather, default type in this case).

Consider the following:

```
template<class U, class T = int>
struct S {
    static constexpr int value = 1;
};

template<>
struct S<double> {
    static constexpr int value = 2;
};
```

Here, `S<double, int>::value` will also be `2`, for the same reason. In the specialization declaration, `U` is explicitly given as `double`, and `T` is implicitly set to `int` because of the default value. And `S<double, float>::value` will be `1`.

Comment: Ah ok. So "template<> struct S<>;" is equivalent to "template<> struct S<int>;" in my special case?

Comment: Yes, pretty much.